# How to set grid width to 100% of ListBox width in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I don't know how to better name this problem, so let's describe it a little bit more specific.
I have ListBox which contains grids with content:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="2" Panel.ZIndex="2">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Grid Height="30" Margin="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Panel.ZIndex="2">
            <!-- some more code -->
        </StackPanel>
        <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding TotalBytesToReceive}" 
            Value="{Binding BytesReceived}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</ListBox>
```

**I want `Grid` to fit `ListBox` width**, so the `ProgressBar` Stretch all over the space, and content of `StackPanel` to be in the middle (it is already done). I was trying to set following properties of grid `width="auto"`, `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` but it also doesn't work.

I also found that setting proper `Setter` in `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` (you can find it in posted code) should do the trick, but it still looks the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in `ItemContainerStyle` set `HorizontalContentAlignment` instead of `HorizontalAlignment`

Comment: Thank you very much, `HorizontalContentAlignment` did the trick. All answers I found earlier was about `HorizontalAlignment`